# Rails: How to add an empty 'required' attribute to a radio_button_tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm trying to use a `radio_button_tag` to generate a radio-button tag like:

```
<input type="radio" ... required>
```

in order to add form validation (I'm using Foundation and trying to make use of the Abide library). The closest I can get is:

```
radio_button_tag 'my_radio', ... , required: ''

# => <input type="radio" ... required="required">
```

This seems to be good enough for Abide to work, but is there a way I can get what I want out of the Rails helper? I've tried `required: true` in place of `required: ''` but it behaves the same.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you. Can you explain your use case? In case you want to make radio button mandatory, you can just make it as selected by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4de8851289077239ecc91473bdba30f8cf6727bb/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/tag_helper.rb#L149

Rails just looks for the presence of a value with "if value". A blank string is considered a value since it isn't nil and that is what triggers rails to include that "required='required'" attribute.

Does Abide really need the tag to be blank? It looks like it may just be checking for the presence of the "required" attribute so it may not care if the attribute has a value or not.

Comment: Rails always adds key/value attributes to html elements and it is considered the same thing required and required="required". The second is actually the preferred way to set attribtues.

Comment: Abide seems to be fine with `required="required"`, I just thought it'd be cleaner without that bit. @Rafal I was able to add a valueless `data-abide` attribute to my form tab with `form_tag ... , data: {abide: ''}` which made me think I could do something similar in the radio-button. Maybe `data` attributes are treated differently. Why is `required="required"` preferable?

Comment: html5 standard allows attribute minimization. xhtml5 does not. So I think that rails follow the xhtml5 which maps better to Hashes.

Answer (score 6):

There wasn't a literal answer to copy/paste so I am providing one.

`<%= radio_button_tag(:model_id, model.id, false, required: 'required') %>`